# How to use @IBAction and @IBOutlet with multiple view controllers in XCode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a problem with Xcode. I am making a test application and I have multiple view controllers connected with a tab bar controller. For each view controller, I obviously have a class. And I use control-drag to add an @IBOutlet/@IBAction. It works. The problem is when I run it, it doesn't compile. I'm guessing it's because the view hasn't loaded yet. Here's the code.

```
class MyViewController1: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myInput: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myInput.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func myButtonFunc(_ sender: UIButton){
        myLabel.text = "The function worked!"
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this application, it like has some kind of error in the AppDelegate. If anyone could help, that would be great. I am very new to Swift/Xcode. Swift's syntax is quite different to C++/C!

Comment: Without showing us the actual error you see, it's really hard to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that I can see with the code given would be that the `myLabel` IBoutlet is `nil`. Make sure you connected the IBOutlet to a Label in the interface builder. Hope this helped. Also, to debug errors so you can see the line instead of the AppDelegate, follow the steps below:

Select the breakpoint navigator:

[image: step 1]

Then, click on the `+` at the bottom and select `Exception Breakpoint...`

[image: step 2]

You should now have a breakpoint titled `All Exceptions`. Run the code again, and it will show you the line that the error is on. Most likely it is an issue of a IBOutlet that is not connected.

Hope this helped

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I do believe I did connect it (I control dragged it from the storyboard) but I will try your method btw it does show